# Ubuntu 11.04 change in simple desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am unable to find the way that my system turn in Ubuntu 10 like desktop. currently, my system is showing me the MAC style start menu and side bar. Can anyone know how to switch my ubuntu in simple desktop.

Yours,

Comment: or maybe rather http://askubuntu.com

Comment: I am sorry to know that I asked wrong question but its my first and last mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logout, click on your name, then at the bottom you will have the option to switch off unity by selecting Ubuntu classic mode.